# Powershell piping properties

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell

I'm trying to read appointments in my outlook agenda.
Basically what I'm trying to do is select the 4 most common appointments of a certain date range with DONE in the subject; and chop off everything after the first semicolumn.
I' ve gotten quite far, but I have two issues:

1. I can't filter on the subject. The datefilters work; but only keeping appointments that contain DONE; it seems I have an issue?
2. How would I be able to chop off everything that is written after a : (semicolon)? I assumed I'd be able to whip up something like `$_.subject.substring(0,$_.subject.IndexOf(':'))` but I have no idea where to place this.

```
    $outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
    $calendar = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(9)

    $calendar.items | Where {$_.start -gt [datetime]'01/1/2020' -and $_.end -lt [datetime]'01/31/2020'  -and $_.Suject -like '*Done*'} | group-object -property subject -noelement | sort-object count -Descending | Where-object count -gt 1
```

Comment: Just starting to look a this. Found this typo: `$_.Suject`

Comment: `$_.Subject` contains (a) semicolon(s)?  Use the `.Split()` method: `$_.Subject.Split(';')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have **Outlook**, but I imagine your filter issue was the typo...

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$calendar = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(9)

$calendar.items |
   Where {$_.start -gt [datetime]'01/1/2020' -and 
          $_.end -lt [datetime]'01/31/2020'  -and 
          $_.Subject -like '*Done*'} |
Group -property subject -noelement |
   Where count -gt 1 |
      Sort Count -Descending
```

Not sure where you want to drop text-trailing-semicolon...

Options:

```
$calendar.items | ForEach{
    $_.Subject = $_.Subject.Split(';')[0]
} |
    Where {$_.Start...
```

Or:

```
...
   Where count -gt 1 |
      Sort Count -Descending | ForEach{
          $_.Name = $_.Name.Split(';')[0]
}
```